# TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments

Tags: python

I'm building a class to handle HTTP GET requests using `http.server`, this is what i wrote so far:

```py
class webServerHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    __HOST = "localhost"
    __PORT = 8080

    # Custom GET response
    def do_GET(self):
        page_content = self.htmlHandler()
        self.wfile.write(page_content) # Send web page

    # HTML code
    def htmlHandler(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        msg = '''
        <html><head><title>Test</title></head>
        <body><h1><center>Test</center></h1></body>
        </html>
        '''
        return bytes(msg, "UTF-8") # UTF-8 Format

    # Run the server
    def serverStart(self):
        # init HTTP Daemon
        http_daemon = HTTPServer((self.__HOST, self.__PORT), webServerHandler)
        http_daemon.serve_forever()
        print("Info: Server started")
```

and i execute it with:

```py
server = webServerHandler()
server.serverStart()
```

When i try to execute it it give me this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'request', 'client_address', and 'server'
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's follow the MRO:

```
In [351]: http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__mro__
Out[351]: 
(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler,
 socketserver.StreamRequestHandler,
 socketserver.BaseRequestHandler,
 object)
```

and the `__init__` is defined in `socketserver.BaseRequestHandler`:

```
def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
    self.request = request
    self.client_address = client_address
    self.server = server
    self.setup()
    try:
        self.handle()
    finally:
        self.finish()
```

As you can see you need to provide the needed 3 positional arguments (`request`, `client_address`, `server`) to instantiate the instance as mentioned in the exception.

Answer (score 3):

This error is happening because the `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` has [3 required arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler), and thus your `webServerHandler` class, which extends `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` and doesn't override the constructor *also* has those same required arguments.

You are calling `webServerHandler()` with no arguments, when you *need* to call `webServerHandler` with `request`, `client_address`, and `server` arguments.

Comment: Why does it require those? When I look at the class definition in the code, I see no such requirements, nor any constructor... Aha! The answer is found if you keep going up to further base classes...